Rotate Array Right by K places (brute force)
I found this question over leetcode, as I am learning about arrays now. The problem seems to be in the shifting block of the given code.
Example 1:

Input: nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], k = 3
Output: [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
Explanation:
rotate 1 steps to the right: [7,1,2,3,4,5,6]
rotate 2 steps to the right: [6,7,1,2,3,4,5]
rotate 3 steps to the right: [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]

Example 2:

Input: nums = [-1,-100,3,99], k = 2
Output: [3,99,-1,-100]
Explanation: 
rotate 1 steps to the right: [99,-1,-100,3]
rotate 2 steps to the right: [3,99,-1,-100]

class Solution {
public:
    void rotate(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
        int n = sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0]);
        k = k%n;
        vector<int> temp;
        //storing the elements of the array till k places
        for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            temp.push_back(nums[i]);
        }

        //shifting by k places
        for(int i = k; i<n;i++) {
            nums[i+k] = nums[i];
        }

        //putting the temp back to the place
        int j = 0;
        for(int i = n-k; i < n; i++) {
            nums[i] = nums[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
};

I solved for rotating the array left by k places in my local editor. I get the solution fine.
Here, according to what I know, there is a memory overflow.
I am confident the rest of the code works fine except for the shifting block.

int n = sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0]); is maximum wrong.

You should define int n = nums.size(); + what do you think happens for e.g. a vector of size 10 with k = 5 in the loop for(int i = k; i<n;i++)? Imagine when i is 9, then is nums[i+k] still inside the vector?

sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0]) is for C arrays, not std::vector. For std::vector use the size() method for that.

What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?

See std::rotate.

If (k < size(vec)) std::rotate(begin(vec), begin(vec)+k, end(vec)); and have fun. Don't forget to #include <algorithm>.

@Red.Wave I think you missed that the OP is calling for rotate-right. std::rotate performs a rotate-left operation. Because the OP is calling for rotate-right, if you are going to use std::rotate, you have to use begin(vec) + (vec.size() - k) for the middle argument.

@tbxfreeware For left right rotate use reverse iterators: std::rotate(rbegin(vec), rbegin(vec)+k, rend(vec));.

The problem seems to be in the shifting block of the given code -- This is a one line solution, already solved by using std::rotate.  See this

I found this question over leetcode, as I am learning about arrays now -- Leetcode does not teach you C++,  It is basically a bunch of random puzzle questions for persons who already have experience in the language they will use to solve the puzzle.  It isn't meant for beginner programmers -- if you are just now learning about arrays, spending time on puzzles geared towards experienced programmers will not help.  Also, Leetcode questions are designed where "brute force" will almost never work for the constraints given, and more sophisticated approaches have to be used.

Let's assume your vector is 5 elements long and you do the correct int n = nums.size(); and then you want to rotate by k=3.
In your for-loop, because i == k and k == 3, your first iteration then accesses num[3+3], which is out of bounds and thus crashes.
To implement your rotation algorithm correctly, you have to keep the array size in mind while you are iterating, and adjust your index with the modulo operator inside your loop.
Since this is a learning exercise, I don't wanna give you the entire solution right away - but maybe this is already enough to get you on the right track.

To solve this problem more efficiently use following trick:

Create a void reverse(std::vector<int>& nums, int start, int end) function, that works in O(n/2) time complexity
Reverse array from index 0 to n
Reverse the first partition from [0...k), and the second one, from [k, n)

Done, a vector is shifted to k elements

Your approach is sound, but you have reversed the roles of k and n - k.
As was explained in the comments, you have also misapplied a C-language idiom, for finding the size of an array, to std::vector. A std::vector carries its size within itself. You can retrieve it by calling member function size().

In the first step, push the first n - k elements onto the vector temp.

In the second step, copy the last k elements to the front of the vector.

In the final step, copy n - k elements from the temporary vector, to the end of vector nums (beginning at subscript k).


With your approach, there is no need to use operator %.
Subscripts should use type std::size_t, which is found in the header <cstddef>. The following program is careful to cast k to type std::size_t, and use that type for all of the loop control variables.
// main.cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

// This using declaration allows the LeetCode Solution 
// to be used without modifying its function signature.
// 
// (Shame on you, LeetCode, for teaching programmers to 
// rely on `using namespace std;`.)
using std::vector;

class Solution {
public:
    void rotate(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
        // Preconditions:
        // `nums.size()` lies on the interval [0, 10^5]
        // `k` lies on the interval [0, 10^5]
        assert(nums.size() <= 100'000u);
        assert(k >= 0 && k <= 100'000);

        // Vector size (and subscripts) use type `std::size_t`, from 
        // header <cstddef>. Force `kk` to the half-open interval [0, n).
        std::size_t const n{ nums.size() };
        std::size_t const kk{ static_cast<std::size_t>(k) % n };

        // Treat the "no-rotatation" circumstance as a special case.
        if (kk == 0u)
            return;

        // Copy the first (n - kk) elements into a temporary vector.
        vector<int> temp;
        for (std::size_t i{}; i < (n - kk); ++i) {
            temp.push_back(nums[i]);
        }

        // Copy the last kk elements to the front of the vector.
        std::size_t from{ n - kk };
        for (std::size_t i{}; i < kk; ++i)
            nums[i] = nums[from++];

        // Copy (n - kk) elements from the temporary vector to the 
        // end of vector nums (beginning with subscript `kk`).
        from = 0u;
        for (std::size_t i{ kk }; i < n; ++i)
            nums[i] = temp[from++];
    }
};
class put_vector
{
    std::vector<int> const& v;
public:
    put_vector(std::vector<int> const& v) : v(v) {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ost, put_vector const& pv) {
        ost.put('[');
        if (!pv.v.empty()) {
            ost << pv.v.front();
            for (std::size_t i{ 1u }; i < pv.v.size(); ++i)
                ost << ',' << pv.v[i];
        }
        ost.put(']');
        return ost;
    }
};
void solve(
    std::string_view heading,
    std::vector<int> nums,
    int k)
{
    std::cout
        << heading
        << '\n'
        << "\n  Input: nums = " << put_vector(nums) << ", k = " << k;
    Solution{}.rotate(nums, k);
    std::cout
        << "\n  Output: " << put_vector(nums)
        << "\n\n";
}
int main() {
    std::cout << "LeetCode 189. Rotate Array"
        "\nhttps://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-array/"
        "\n\n";
    solve("Example 1", { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 }, 3);
    solve("Example 2", { -1,-100,3,99 }, 2);
}
// end file: main.cpp

Output
The output matches the examples from the LeetCode website.
LeetCode 189. Rotate Array
https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-array/

Example 1

  Input: nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], k = 3
  Output: [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]

Example 2

  Input: nums = [-1,-100,3,99], k = 2
  Output: [3,99,-1,-100]

std::copy
In the comments below, @Evg points out that vector elements can be copied using std::copy (and iterators). I avoided using those above, because I wanted to stay within the style of the OP. If, however, you are comfortable with them, the program can be greatly simplified.
std::copy allows you to remove the loops, and with them out of the way, the resulting code is both easier to read, and easier to maintain.
As used below, std::copy takes three arguments, all of which are iterators. The first two describe the range to copy from: [first, last). The third identifies the destination.
// Copy the first (n - k) elements into a temporary vector.
auto const nk{ n - k };
vector<int> temp(nk);
std::copy(nums.cbegin(), nums.cbegin() + nk, temp.begin());

// Copy the last k elements to the front of the vector.
std::copy(nums.cbegin() + nk, nums.cend(), nums.begin());

// Copy (n - k) elements from the temporary vector to the 
// end of vector `nums` (beginning with subscript `k`).
std::copy(temp.cbegin(), temp.cend(), nums.begin() + k);

Side note
As suggested by @Jarod42, using std::rotate reduces this to a one-liner.

You don't need all these loops to copy elements. Just use pairs of iterators.

Agreed. I was trying to stay within the style used by the OP. ;)
